# Manually implementing client side session

Tags: servlets, blackberry, java-me, midp

I have a simple servlet which is adding a session variable. To request the session variable I can just from within another servlet I can use -

```
request.getSession().getAttribute
```

But how can I request this variable on client side that does not implement the servlet spec. In this case im using MIDP.

```
public class SetTestStartTime extends HttpServlet{

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            Long currentTimeMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("time", currentTimeMilliSeconds);


        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot read session variable in client side. but you can write your session data to http header and you can read them from j2me applicaiton.

in servlet

```
public class SetTestStartTime extends HttpServlet{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Long currentTimeMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("time", currentTimeMilliSeconds);
    response.addHeader("time", request.getSession().getAttribute("time"));
}
}
```

and in j2me

```
HttpConnection con = ....;
String time = con.getHeaderField("time");
```